# How to configure request/socket timeout in JBOSS 6?

Tags: jboss

I have a request which download a pdf file. This might take more than 60 seconds but if exceeds 1 minute, I get the timeout error. Is there any way i can increase server's timeout in Jboss EAP 6.

I have already tried "org.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" but not worked for me, available only after JBOSS 7.2.

Comment: Which EAP 6 are you talking about? That "JBOSS 7.2" you mention most certainly is "JBoss *AS* 7.2", which I think would correspond to JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4

Comment: It's based on JBoss AS 7.5, so that "available only after JBOSS 7.2" doesn't matter (it's certainly not JBoss EAP 7.2 which was published a month ago, I've been using this DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT on EAP 6.1)

Comment: Are you using a standalone or domain? Can you include an extract of the configuration where you've been trying to set the connection timeout?

Comment: BTW since you're using JBoss EAP you should have access to RedHat's KnowledgeBase, in which case you might want to read [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/456733) which documents how to modify the timeout.